# WP CLI "Error establishing a database connection" in localhost (MAMP)

Tags: wp-cli

I get this error when I try to create something with WP CLI:

```
Error establishing a database connection. This either means that the username and password information in your `wp-config.php` file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at `localhost`. This could mean your host’s database server is down.
```

But I can open the site with the link: http://localhost:8888/projectname

Any idea?

Comment: Here's another error that shows up on the command line for this (at least in my case). Adding it in hopes Google will help people searching for it + "wp-cli": `Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in `

Answer (score 50):

Go into your `wp-config.php` and change your `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost.

Credit goes to Craig Wayne above in the comments.

Comment: In MAMP Pro I also had to check "Allow network access to MySQL" for this to work.

Comment: I tried this but no help. I'm using Bedrock boilerplate. I went thru wp-config and .env file over and over again, went thru MAMPs configs over and over again. Debugged the wb-db.php file. 

Then I removed the # from the DB_HOST row in .env, and all is good.

Comment: @Tom Try this https://tommcfarlin.com/installing-wp-cli-with-mamp/ before you change the host in `wp-config.php`. It should work.

Comment: @NickM - I realise this is an old comment, but hopefully you see this reply. Where is "Allow network access to MySQL" option located? I've got MAMP Pro 4.4.1, and I've been unable to find this setting you mention. UPDATE: I found it, on MySQL service. Unfortunately in my case it is already ticked, along with "only from this Mac".

Comment: Figured out it requires not just `127.0.0.1` but also the port, which for MAMP PRO is `127.0.0.1:8889`

Comment: i wanted to add here that this is generally correct, but there's a slight adjustment needed for devKinsta if you're running that versus MAMP. You can find your db host info in the devKinsta panel and then make the respective ip:port changes in wp config, however to run wp search-replace, but then you need to switch back to the original devKinsta host to get it working as a site again. there might be a better solution, but that's working for me.

Answer (score 12):

For me, the answer was changing the setting for `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1:8889` instead of `localhost` in `wp-config.php`, and also checking the box to "Allow network access to MySQL" in the MySQL settings. Getting the port set to the port that MAMP Pro is using for the database was the critical missing piece that I didn't see in the other answers here. YMMV.

Comment: +10 for this.  Though I'm curious why some users need to add the port and some don't need to

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to use the MAMP PHP binary.
You can check the which PHP Version WP CLI is running with

```
php wp-cli.phar --info
```

To use the latest MAMP PHP you need to modify your bash or zsh profile:

```
PHP_VERSION=$(ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1)
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

Make sure to reload the profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Make sure that the changes are applied correctly:

```
  php wp-cli.phar --info
```

Comment: That first command just gives the error `Could not open input file: wp-cli.phar`

Comment: Did you run the command in the wordpress root folder?

Comment: yes, but there is no `wp-cli.phar` file in the [root of the WP directory](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress).

Comment: Here you can find more informations how to install the wp-cli.phar:
(https://wp-cli.org/)

Comment: @FelixEve if during the installation you've moved `wp-cli.phar` under `/usr/local/bin/wp`, you can issue `wp --info` instead: the displayed `PHP binary` should be the one under your WP installation.

Answer (score 2):

There's two parts of this that need to work together:

— You need to switch from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and add the port number at the end. For me, it was `127.0.0.1:3306`.

The port number is in the MySQL panel in Mamp.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step1: check if your mysql server is running
Step2: if yes then you can log in to mysql using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

then enter your password: ( you must use this command from terminal )
then use following command to ensure that database exists:

```
show databases;
grant all privileges on database_name.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

now edit the wp-config.php file and search for

```
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Now restart the server and try to login to your wordpress dashboard.
I hope it helps.

Comment: "mysql -u root -p" gives me "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: when you set up your mysql database, you must have entered a password. Use that password.
If you didn't configure password at the time of mysql database set up, just hit enter instead of any password.

Comment: I did what you wrote. Can connect to the database with "mysql -u root -p". Also the privileges are granted. But the error is still there.

Comment: I've found that if i change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in my wp-config.php, everything works fine... i feel like theres a bigger problem here

Comment: With a clean install of WordPress v3.6.9 and WP-CLI v1.5.1 @CraigWayne 's solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, besides the aforementioned error message, I also got the warnings below:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531
PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562
Warning: mysql_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562
Warning: mysql_connect(): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep), this issue happens because the default charset for MySQL 8.0 is `utfmb4`.

In fact, I could replicate the error by upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0

I solved the issue by exporting the database, downgrading to MySQL 5.7 and re-importing the data. I also ran tests on MariaDB 10.3 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to do what eknows proposed in his solution (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/313862/172520) AND of course enabling network access to MySQL for my Mac (using MAMP Pro).

Answer (score 0):

You may also get this error with certain WP operations if you are using it on a WordPress multisite, in which case you need to specify an URL eg. --url=mysite.org